# How to automate the sideloading of an app to to MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Hi I am looking to automate the process of sideloading an app to MS Teams - essentially programmatically uploading a zipped manifest.json file from my computer to MS Teams. This process is detailed manually [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload) by Microsoft.

I have been unable to find any endpoints or tools that do this task so far, so any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: It is not supported to side load using endpoint. If you are using Teams toolkit, you can publish app to app catalog. Check following reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/publish#publish-to-your-organization

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru Thanks for your feedback, but I wouldn't call that link automating this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a few options here. The two that I believe are the best for my use case are this [powershell cmdlet](https://New-TeamsApp%20(MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell)) and [this CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teamsfx-cli). The former is more suitable for my use case, so I will provide a snippet of what works for my case:

```
# install the modules needed for this cmdlet
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

# login to the cli
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

# upload the app
New-TeamsApp -DistributionMethod <distribution_method> -Path <path_to_zip_file>
```

**Note** there are two options for `<distribution_method>`: `global` and `organization`. The latter makes more sense for my test use case, but I wanted to mention the former in case it makes more sense for someone else.