# How to side load the customised app in MS teams through CLI

Tags: microsoft-teams

How to side load the customised app in MS teams through TeamsFx CommandLine ?

I saw this answer [How to automate the sideloading of an app to to MS Teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008784/how-to-automate-the-sideloading-of-an-app-to-to-ms-teams)
Could you please let me know how you are automating this upload part and checking the deployed app?

And also can we use distribution_method organization if we want to test the custom app locally ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: @alex-bishka Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `teamsfx publish`, but first you need to run `teamsfx provision`.

You can also use [Teams Toolkit for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teams-toolkit-fundamentals?pivots=visual-studio-code) if you prefer to have a UI for this workflow. The extensions use the TeamsFx CLI.

If you want to setup CI/CD, take a look at this guide: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/How-to-automate-cicd-pipelines